# Shipping method filtering based on order total

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I have a magento 2.2.3 site. In checkout we have enabled  two shipping options. Table rates and free shipping. Orders above 100$ we provide free shipping charges. But sometimes this does not work
Suppose, the subtotal for particular order is 160$. After discounts or promotions etc order total comes as 60$. Then in the checkout free shipping options should not be displayed and table rates should be applied.  Checkout shows both options. What I want is to display only one of the option based on the Order total not the subtotal. 
Could anyone please advice on this ??

Comment: how to apply condition on whole shipping collection

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a plugin of ShipmentEstimationInterface class.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface">
    <plugin name="allow_company_shipping_methods" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ShippingPlugin"/>
</type>
```

**ShippingPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


class ShippingPlugin
{
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
       $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
   /**
     * Allow shipping methods
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface[] $methods
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface[] $methods
     */
    public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress(\Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject, $methods) 
    {
        $grandTotal = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        foreach($methods as $key => &$method) {
            if($method->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping' && $grandTotal < 60) {
                unset($methods[$key]);
            }
        } 
        return $methods;

    }


}
```

I hope it will work for you. Let me know in case any further assistance needed.

Comment: Hi Ramkishan thanks for the suggestion. I will try this out.

Comment: Any suggestions guys ?